# How to create cluster column chart in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I need to plot the ratios of 2 categories over 4 groups in order of a nice easy understandable comparison.

i did this so far and got 2 plots:

```
x <- c(0.50, 0.53, 0.49, 0.47)
names(x) <- c("Mütter über Söhne", "Mütter über Töchter", "Väter über Söhne", 
              "Väter über Töchter")
barplot(x, xlab= "Gruppe", ylab = "Anteil Wörter abstrakt-logisch ", main = 
        "abstrakt-logisch")

x1 <- c(0.51, 0.54, 0.46, 0.49)
names(x1) <- c("Mütter über Söhne", "Mütter über Töchter", "Väter über Söhne", "Väter über Töchter")
barplot(x1, xlab= "Gruppe", ylab = "Anteil Wörter kreativ-verbal ", main = "kreativ-verbal")
```

I want to compare the ratios of words in 2 categories over 4 groups. so first ratio from category 1 (0.50) compared to first ratio of category 2 (0.51) over the group "Mütter über Söhne". i also need a naming for x-axis = "groups" and y-axis = "ratios of words". 
it should look something like that:

[image]

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Thanks alot!!! this looks great! if theres a way to erase the grid in the backround behind the bars, then it would be perfect. otherwise i can totally use this like that in my masterthesis.

Comment: @Maurits Evers but i think, my answer was good as well :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with `ggplot2`, you can use this basic way.

```
x1 <- c(0.50, 0.53, 0.49, 0.47)
x2 <- c(0.51, 0.54, 0.46, 0.49)
group <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(1, 20), ylim = c(0, 0.6))
abline(h = 0:6/10, col = "grey")
barplot(rbind(x1, x2), beside = T, space = c(0.5, 2), axes = F,
        col = c("grey10", "grey"), xlab = "groups", ylab = "ratios of words",
        names.arg = group, add = T)
legend(x = "topright", legend = c("category 1", "category 2"),
       fill = c("grey10", "grey"), box.col = NA)
mtext(0:6/10, side = 2, at = 0:6/10)
```

`space` is specified by two numbers, where the first is the space between bars in the same group, and the second the space between the groups.

[image]

Comment: this is not related what PO has asked. You first need to define the dataset, in right way and your `rbind` does not do that

Comment: wow thanks!! that looks great! is there a way to name the different colours of the bars (black = category 1, grey = cateogory 2) and also the x- and y-axis?

Comment: this is not still the proper dataset. You have not considered `group` in your dataset.

Comment: Maybe my answer is heavy and primitive, but I don't think it's wrong. The data provided is vector, so I use a vector way to do visualization. Defining a dataset and groups is necessary in ggplot2 instead of everywhere.

Comment: @LauraAtaraxia I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer of yours. You need to first define your dataset in a proper way:

```
dt<-data.frame(
  group= c("Mütter über Söhne", "Mütter über Töchter", "Väter über Söhne", "Väter über Töchter"),
  category=c("category1","category1","category1","category1",    "category2","category2","category2","category2"),
  ratio= c(0.50, 0.53, 0.49, 0.47,  0.51, 0.54, 0.46, 0.49))

head(dt)
```

And then use the ggplot to draw it

```
    library(ggplot2)


ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=group, y=ratio, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+                #Remove background
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

and the final output is:

[image]

Comment: @Laura Ataraxia i have updated my answer, as you wished

Comment: now i get an error message:

"Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state"

Comment: @LauraAtaraxia make sure you have installed the `ggplot2` lpackage in your RStudio. You can watch this video to learn how to install packages https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHPcUthPk_c

Comment: i know how to install a package, thanks :) everythings fine! thanks for your answer, helped alot!!

Comment: @LauraAtaraxia could you please accept my answer.