# How to create cluster column chart with R?

Tags: r

I have data sheet of 3 columns - month , p1 ,p2
I need to display a grouped barplot of p1 and p2. x axis is months .
I want to know how to display percentage on the graph.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide sample of dataset, and a verified output

Comment: check edit @Salman

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015997/how-to-create-cluster-column-chart-in-r/52016748#52016748

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouped barplot in R with error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768219/grouped-barplot-in-r-with-error-bars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image which you have provided is called cluster barchart. **You need to redefine your dataset since it does not give you the cluster barchart.**

Create dataset:

```
dt<-data.frame(
  month= c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Agu","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",
           "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Agu","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),
  category=c("P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1","P1",
             "P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2","P2"),
  value=sample(50000:100000,24))

head(dt)
```

and then draw it

```
 library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=month, y=value, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I cant use fill , bcuz these are two different columns. I used reshape and scales for this particular graph

Comment: @FatmaZahra do you know `ggplot`?

Comment: yes I know . but i dont know how to make a cluster barchart in ggplot\

Comment: so should i add a column called category ?

Comment: @FatmaZahra Yes, for sure. the `category` is your groups. If you dont do that, then `ggplot` does not understand how to cluster your bars.
please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: thank you ! and what if i have to display the difference of each month in another plot ?

Comment: and since i am importing the table from excel I donno how to add the category column

Comment: About importing data from excel. There is no easy way. You either must write so `R` code to fix you dataset pragmatically, or spend time and do it manually.

Comment: @FatmaZahra about making another plot, it is better to ask another question for it. I think, you must fill the barcharts with the different values, but i am not sure if i get you correctly or not.